# Execute multiple webrequests in WP7?

Tags: windows-phone-7, httpwebrequest, backgroundworker

I have a list of addresses that i want to visit using httpWebRequest.
All i need is the statuscode returned by the server.

I have tried to foreach through them and begin a httpWebRequest on each of them, but then i only receive the callback from the last one.
It seems like only one webrequest is allowed at a time.

I'm having quite a hard time understanding how to do this without the GetResponse, which is not allowed in silverlight.

The code is running in a backgroundworker.
And i am using Mango - WP7.1

How do i solve that?

```
foreach (var current in Addresses)
        {
            var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(current);
            request.BeginGetResponse(r =>
            {
                try
                {
                    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(r);
                    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                    {
                        //BOOM RECEIVED
                    });
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    Debug.WriteLine("Error in EndGetResponse");
                }
            }, null);
        }
```

Thanks in advance =)

Comment: Yes, i am using mango =)

Comment: What kind of "BOOM" do you recieve?

Comment: I receive the statuscode and then i update the model. The BOOM was just to illustrate that something was received =)

Comment: I wonder if you could iterate like that in a Caliburn micro corouting where each request would yield return, process return, keep going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem of a single response is most likely being caused by your use of anonymous methods and the the way scoping works when you put these inside loops. You are throwing away the earlier request references on each step through the loop.

See my blogpost on the topic here http://csainty.blogspot.com/2010/10/windows-phone-7asynchronous-programming.html

The simplest way to illustrate this is to rewrite your code with full methods, this forces you to consider the scope instead of just blindly referening external variables in your delegates.

```
foreach (var current in Addresses)
{
  var request = HttpWebRequest.Create(current);
  request.BeginGetResponse(EndGetResponse, new RequestState { Request = request, Address = current });
}


private void EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult result) {
  try {
    var state = (RequestState)result.AsyncState;
    var response = (HttpWebResponse)state.Request.EndGetResponse(result);
    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(GotResponse, state.Address, response.StatusCode);
  } catch (Exception) {
    Debug.WriteLine("Error in EndGetResponse");
  }
}

private void GotResponse(Address address, HttpStatusCode code) {
  //BOOM RECEIVED
}

public class RequestState {
  HttpWebRequest Request { get; set; }
  Address Address { get; set; }
}
```

Once you solve the scoping issues you can rewrite back into anonymos methods for stylistic reasons if you like.

This will only solve your first problem of getting all the responses back however, I assume you also need to run some code when all the requests are complete to check the status of the whole batch?
That is a different problem altogether.

You can not use WaitOne() or anything like that, it will lock your thread and stop the requests from actually running at all. You will probably want to call off to another method in you BOOM code that stores away the result and checks if all the results are in yet.

Comment: I see how using full methods instead of anonymous will solve the problem. But how will i be able to rewrite it to anonymous methods afterwards, if the problem itself is the use of anonymous methods? I'm curious because doing it the anonymous way makes it easier to reference the objects in the loop. In my project, the address is located on an object, and the collection i'm iterating through is actually a list of those objects. And when the request response is received, i need the object that started the request to save some of the returned values.

Comment: @Moulde Thats the problem, you can't just reference objects outside the anonymous method, my blog post explains what happens when you do. I have updated the answer to show how you can pass more than a single piece of state through to the response.